# wordpress ajax request returns 'POST .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED' for data more than 1mb

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am submitting a jquery ajax form from the frontend. And uploading a blob (nothing but a variable of string) as .txt file to WordPress using `wp_handle_upload()`. everything works just fine until the file size reaches ~1mb. It always shows the error `'POST .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED'`

But when I try the same request (without refreshing the page) with blob size approx to ~1mb (exactly 1033268 bytes) of data by reducing the string, it works fine.

Note: the same error appeared when I tried to save the content of the blob as a string to the wp post meta field. I thought uploading it as file might solve the problem. but it still has it.

Could you please help me submit blob/string that is of size more than 300mb through ajax?

[image: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED]

**Edit:** the character count of the string is 1153975. I tried saving this as raw string in WordPress post content in backend. but even the backend wordpress admin is facing the same problem.

I also tried changing php.ini's max_input_vars to 4,00,000 (my hosting is namecheap shared (steller plus, at the time of writing)) but nothing seems to work. I guess wordpress by default can't handle this long string.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted hosting support and the issue was with ModSecurity (ModSecurity is an open-source toolkit for real-time web application monitoring, logging, and access control). It was blocking my post requests considering it as a potential threat.

Disabling ModSecurity solved the problem. (Disabling it makes the server vulnerable so we need to have our own security measures for the site with it is disabled).